# How to return a URL and submit the form using onchange

Tags: php, javascript, html

Firstly, there may be a similar question answered amoungst the site but after carefully considering what solutions and problems I'm still stumped as to what to do.

I'm looking to return a URL and post my users to a page of the chosen URL from a select list.

Currently it works using the normal submit button using the following code;

```
<form id="formurl" name="formurl" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return getURL(this.url.value)">
            <!-- begin postcode list -->
            <select size="1" name="url" id="posctode_srch" onchange="this.form.submit()">
              <option value="e1-office-space/">E1</option>
              <option value="e7-office-space/">E7</option>
              <option value="e10-office-space/">E10</option>
              <option value="e11-office-space/">E11</option>
              <option value="e14-office-space/">E14</option>
              <option value="e15-office-space/">E15</option>
              <option value="e16-office-space/">E16</option>
              <option value="e17-office-space/">E17</option>
              <option value="ec1-office-space/">EC1</option>
              <option value="ec2-office-space/">EC2</option>
              <option value="ec3-office-space/">EC3</option>
              <option value="ec4-office-space/">EC4</option>
            </select>

            <input type="image" src="images/graphics/new/btn_go.png" class="go_btn" width="119" border="0" value="submit" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'AreaSearchForm',,, false]);" alt="Area search submit" />

          </form>
```

I'm looking to use post but I am testing it with get to see what result is created when choosing an option. when the form is set to get i'm seeing `?url=e7-office-space%2F` so am I safe to assume it's working to some degree but there is something missing for the output to just take the value of the option and nothing more?

Being new to this kind of stuff i'm guessing it's a php / html problem as the functionality is there it's just a misused element somewhere so if anyone can help me see where i'm going wrong i'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: What does getURL do? Also very poor practice to add onclick to a submit image

Comment: Firstly, `onSubmit` should be `onsubmit` (case-sensitive), secondly, you're looking for something like `onsubmit="this.action=getUrl(...); return true;"`

Comment: onSubmit is only mandatory lowercase in some doctypes. It is an HMTL attribute

Comment: Don't use image with `onclick` to submit a form because when you hover on the image, the cursor doesn't change, so user may think, no action will take place when you click that image and in turn won't click the link unless the image says, "Click me". It is good to put that image in `a` or `button` tag and add the add onclick event to that element. Lately, in CSS3 the `cursor` property along with `:hover` psuedo-class help you change the cursor but it is not supported in many browser.

Comment: It is a submit image so it will have a hand cursor

Comment: I'm looking to move away from the button / image with the need for the onchange to work, it does for now have the "go" text so as it does appear to be functional.

The getURL has come about with me trying to get things to work, I was under the impression that the getURL was to pull the base i.e test.com then this value was to pull the e10-office-space/ part into the url and submit (test.com/e10-office-space/). I understand I may have this completely wrong so bare with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three things -

1. setting the url
2. setting the google stuff
3. submitting the form if not in the submit event

In the code below you can omit the image if you can rely on javascript only

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/MHw4A/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("formurl").onsubmit=function() {
      var val = this.url.value;
      if (val=="") {
         alert("Please select a value");
         return false; 
      }
      this.action="http://bing.com/search?q="+val;
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'AreaSearchForm',,, false]);
  }
  document.getElementById("posctode_srch").onchange=function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val=="") return;
    this.form.onsubmit(); // not 100% sure but this should not trigger twice
    this.form.submit();   // since this is not triggering onsubmit
  }
}
```

using

```
<form id="formurl" name="formurl" method="post" action="">
             <!-- begin postcode list -->
            <select size="1" name="url" id="posctode_srch">
              <option value="">Please select</option>
              <option value="e1-office-space/">E1</option>
              <option value="e7-office-space/">E7</option>
              <option value="e10-office-space/">E10</option>
              <option value="e11-office-space/">E11</option>
              <option value="e14-office-space/">E14</option>
              <option value="e15-office-space/">E15</option>
              <option value="e16-office-space/">E16</option>
              <option value="e17-office-space/">E17</option>
              <option value="ec1-office-space/">EC1</option>
              <option value="ec2-office-space/">EC2</option>
              <option value="ec3-office-space/">EC3</option>
              <option value="ec4-office-space/">EC4</option>
            </select>
            <input type="image" src="images/graphics/new/btn_go.png" 
            class="go_btn" width="119" border="0" value="submit" 
            alt="Area search submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks mplungjan, this code is working by your example but when implementing it I'm still getting no functionality from the onchange so it must be something else stopping it.


I'll continue to look at what is happening but I can't deny you the correct answer with a working example

Comment: Look in the console. Perhaps there is an error from somewhere. Also note I added a "Please Select" to allow the selection of E1

Comment: I think I may have found the issue, again thanks for your help and I see what you did there with the "please select" so thanks.